# XMLRPC API call not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cors, xml-rpc

Am working in a HTML5 + PhoneGap Mobile App development using XMLRPC method. Its working perfectly in Mobile Apps. And for showcase we upload the HTML5 section in a subdomain and set CORS in server.
we provide `Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*` in Server for the cross domain access.

Then When I checked its not working in `chrome` and shows

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl:1234/xmlrpc/common. Invalid HTTP status code 404
```

When same URL works fine in `Safari` ! When i tried to login its works correctly and gets the result.

My code is ;

```
  $.xmlrpc({    
          url: 'http://myurl:1234/xmlrpc/common',    
          methodName: 'login',
          crossDomain: true,   
          params: ['database','username','password'],     
            success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {             
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); 
            },     
            error: OnError     });
```

How Can i solve this issue? Its working OK in Sfari but why not chrome even set CORS ?